# Modify asp textbox before HttpRequest.ValidateString() is called

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I've built a regex function that I'd like to call to clean up the text pasted into an asp textbox but it looks like HttpRequest.ValidateString() is called prior to the execution of the buttons event handler. Is it possible to run the text through my function prior to it getting validated?

Comment: Is this a JS regex function running on the client, or VB on server? Is the server ASP.NET Core, MVC or WebForms?

Comment: @MarcL.It is a webform app using VB on the server. I'm not that good with JS but I can use it if necessary.

Comment: So far the only way I've found to do this is to set ValidateRequestMode to disabled on the textbox and call my function on the event handler. It appears there might be a way to override LoadPostData method and do this as well which I may try to do eventually. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/358993/Examining-Request-Validation-with-ASP-NET

Comment: Maybe you could run your clean up subroutine on the TEXTBOX_ONTEXTCHANGED event instead? Since you are running VB on the server you can write it as a serverside event. (Ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.ontextchanged(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2)

Comment: @Zeddy Funny thing is I tried that but whenever I modified the text in the textbox it never would fire that event.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the ONCHANGED event and you were right it did not work straight off initially,

A quick search revealed [THIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.ontextchanged?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Web_UI_WebControls_TextBox_OnTextChanged_System_EventArgs_) reference page...

So trying it out, everything works fine.

**Default.Aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head runat="server">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <div>
        The event TextBox1_TextChanged() is raised when the text changes in the textbox<br />
        The TextBox1_TextChanged event calls the CapitaliseText subroutine.<br />
        The Capitalisetext subroutine changes the text in textbox2 to the same as Textbox1 with the FIRST letter capitalised.<br />
        If the first letter in Textbox1 is NOT lower case then Textbox2 does not change<br />
        <br />
        All this is done without clicking the submit button.<br />
        The code runs on the server not the client.<br />
        <br />
        <br />
        Textbox1 -
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" ViewStateMode="Enabled"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <br />
        Textbox-2 - <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        Submit Form -
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit Form" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        Textbox2 Contains -
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <br />
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Default.Aspx.Vb**

```
Partial Class _Default
  Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

  Dim FormWasSubmitted As Boolean

  Protected Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    'run my regex
    CapitaliseText(sender, e)
  End Sub

  Sub CapitaliseText(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    '
    Dim XString As String

    'get textbox1.text
    XString = sender.Text
    If Trim(XString) <> "" Then
      'if first chracter is not caps
      If (Char.IsLower(XString.Chars(0))) Then
            TextBox2.Text = Char.ToUpper(XString.Chars(0)) + XString.Substring(1, XString.Length - 1)
        UpdateLabel()
      End If
    End If
  End Sub

  Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    FormWasSubmitted = True
    UpdateLabel()
  End Sub

  Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    UpdateLabel()
  End Sub

  Sub UpdateLabel()
    If FormWasSubmitted Then
      If Trim(TextBox2.Text) <> "" Then
        Label1.Text = TextBox2.Text & "[Submitted]"
      Else
        Label1.Text = "Nothing"
      End If
    Else
      If Trim(TextBox2.Text) <> "" Then
        Label1.Text = TextBox2.Text
      Else
        Label1.Text = "Nothing"
      End If
    End If
  End Sub
End Class
```

Note that the definition of the text box includes

- AutoPostback = True
- ViewStateMode = Enabled

Since I dont know what processing you are carrying out once the form has been submitted, there is a small chance it may not work(?)

It works fine in that example though.
See if that helps at all and don't forget to read the referenced link

[Netframework-4.7.2#System_Web_UI_WebControls_TextBox_OnTextChanged_System_EventArgs_](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.ontextchanged?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Web_UI_WebControls_TextBox_OnTextChanged_System_EventArgs_)